# Can't get curl response after updating port number and checksum in TC with ebpf

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, xdp-bpf, skb

I am trying to reroute packets with destination port 80 to 5432 using ebpf. I am locally running nginx on port 80 and postgresql on port 5432. What I would like is whenever I execute `curl localhost:80`, my program will change the port number to 5432 and I will get the results of executing `curl localhost:5432`. Both nginx and postgresql are installed and deployed locally without using any containers. All I am changing is the port number. No ip address is changed.

I have written an ebpf program to be attached to the TC hook. Since the three way handshake is established in the `lo` interface on my device, This program is attached on `iface=lo` and attempts to rewrite any packet with destination port=80. I used two methods to recalculate the checksum after the port rewrite, but both methods produce the same error:

```c
static __always_inline __u16 csum_fold_helper(__u32 csum) {
    __u32 sum;
    sum = (csum>>16) + (csum & 0xffff);
    sum += (sum>>16);
    return ~sum;                                                                                       
}

SEC("tc_cls")
int tc_egress(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)skb->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)skb->data;
    struct ethhdr *eth;
    struct iphdr *iph;
    struct tcphdr *tcph;
    eth = data;
    if ((void *)eth + sizeof(*eth) > data_end) {
        return TC_ACT_OK;
    }
    if (eth->h_proto != __bpf_htons(0x0800)) {
        return TC_ACT_OK;
    }
    iph = data + sizeof(*eth);
    if ((void *)iph + sizeof(*iph) > data_end) {
        return TC_ACT_OK;
    }
    if (iph->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP) {
        return TC_ACT_OK;
    }
    tcph = data + sizeof(*eth) + sizeof(*iph);
    if ((void *)tcph + sizeof(*tcph) > data_end) {
        return TC_ACT_OK;
    }
    if (tcph->dest == __bpf_htons(80)) {
        // update checksum method #1
        // __u64 from = tcph->dest;
        // __u16 new_port = __bpf_htons(5432);
        // tcph->dest = new_port;
        // __u64 res = bpf_skb_store_bytes(skb, ETH_HLEN + sizeof(struct iphdr) + 2, &(new_port), 2, BPF_F_RECOMPUTE_CSUM);
        // update checksum method #2
        __u16 new_port = __bpf_htons(5432);
        __u16 old_csum = tcph->check;
        __u32 sum = bpf_csum_diff(&tcph->dest, 2, &new_port, 2, 0);
        __u16 csum = csum_fold_helper(sum);
        tcph->dest = new_port;
        bpf_l4_csum_replace(skb, ETH_HLEN + sizeof(struct iphdr) + 16, old_csum, csum, BPF_F_PSEUDO_HDR);
        }
    return TC_ACT_OK;
}
```

I have seen some posts regarding this issue (most of them involve changing ip addresses) and I have tried to follow the advice, but none of it worked on my program. Tcpdump is used to verify activity on port 5432, and I can see that packets are arriving. All packets with the S flag show incorrect checksum, and R show correct checksum. However, when I detach the ebpf program and run a simple curl on localhost:5432, all packets seem to show an incorrect checksum even if I do get a curl response. Hence, I would like some help checking whether the checksum is correctly updated and whether I am missing other steps to complete the program.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that linux does checksum validation for traffic over the loopback interface since the packet is never actually sent via a network device. So this might be a red herring.

Comment: Could you share the tcpdump output of failing case? It's currently not super clear what the issue is.